# How to overlap images in div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

i'm trying to make a blackjack game and i want to overlap cards. It's supposed that the following code should do that, but i just got a column of cards.

I looked at another similar questions, but i couldn't get what i'm doing wrong

Thanks in advance!

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 46, 0);
  color: white;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  left: 100px;
  margin-left: -75px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Blackjack</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header class="title">
    Blackjack
  </header>

  <div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col text-center">

      <button class="btn btn-danger">New Game</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Hit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Stand</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row container">
    <div class="col">

      <h1>Player <small>0</small> Points</h1>
      <div id="player-cards">
        <img class="card" src="assets/cartas/10C.png">
        <img class="card" src="assets/cartas/10C.png">
        <img class="card" src="assets/cartas/10C.png">
        <img class="card" src="assets/cartas/10C.png">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm totally newbie, so maybe my error is stupid, but i'll really appreciate some help, because i can't find the error or the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 46, 0);
  color: white;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#player-cards {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  left: 100px;
  margin-left: -75px;
}

img.card{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
}
img.card{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
}

img.card:nth-child(2) {     
  transform: translate(0, 50%);

} 
img.card:nth-child(3) {      
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
 
} 
img.card:nth-child(4) {     
  transform: translate(0, 150%);     
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Blackjack</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header class="title">
    Blackjack
  </header>

  <div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col text-center">

      <button class="btn btn-danger">New Game</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Hit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Stand</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row container">
    <div class="col">

      <h1>Player <small>0</small> Points</h1>
      <div id="player-cards">
        <img class="card" src="assets/cartas/10C.png">
        <img class="card" src="assets/cartas/10C.png">
        <img class="card" src="assets/cartas/10C.png">
        <img class="card" src="assets/cartas/10C.png">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Images are overlapping now, but what i would like to get is to that next image cover half of the images below and so on, not to get a pile of images.  is it possible?

Comment: I edited my post. Do you want that result?